# Swift error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_l386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

I get an error when trying to execute this code:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_l386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
```

Let FWeight line is highlighted in red.

Let BWeight line is highlighted in Yellow.

---

```
import UIKit

class detailedViewController: UIViewController {

    static var cc : Food!


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        //Click on a meal, get to detail, displays all of it, go back one step: press chicken wont work. Everytime we switch to different meal it will recalculate.

        let Rweight = Int((detailedViewController.cc.RProteins / 100)*Double(ViewController.minimum))

        print(detailedViewController.cc)

        let Fweight = Int((detailedViewController.cc.FProteins / 100)*Double(ViewController.minimum))

        print(Fweight)

        let Bweight = Int((detailedViewController.cc.BProteins / 100)*Double(ViewController.minimum))

        print(Rweight)

    }
```

This page should show different meals, and when you press on the meal on the table it should display how much you should eat of that food, in 3 different states either raw, fried or boiled. The method above should calculate how much protein there is in 1 gram of the food and times that by the users weight, to see how much they have to consume. Currently my table meals are 100g, so thats why I divide by 100 in the method.

Comment: What is `ViewController` and how is `cc` set? By the way: The limitation of 8 characters for variable names has been cancelled at least 20 years ago ;-)

Comment: At first I'd check your static cc var is not nil. You defined it as an implicitly unwrapped optional. If you access it and it's value is `nil` you get a runtime exception. If you can, try defining `cc` as an optional Food (`Food?`). This way the compiler will help you avoiding this kind of situations.

Comment: I don't see super.viewWillAppear at the beginning. It might not be the issue but you need to call that method compulsorily